# Is it possible to debug (step-through) expanded Haxe macro code?

Tags: haxe

This one is for build macros but would appreciate answer for other macro types as well.

I'd like to step-through the generated code by `@:autoBuild(hxparse.ParserBuilderImpl.build())`, eval debugger doesn't seem to work for this case. Even more specifically, I'd like to see which part of the code causes `(WUnusedPattern) This case is unused` but would prefer more generic answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can connect a debugger to a macro, but for purposes of figuring out what's wrong with generated expression you can use `haxe.macro.ExprTools.toString(expr)`.

Comment: Tried that but output is thousands of lines of code... If I could use such output instead of macro, I'd be able to find the error but I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: If you are generating the switch-block yourself, you could print just the case patterns _or_ assemble a separate switch-block with cases that contain no code - that should be easier to get to compile. You can also use `@:pos` to attach real or fake positions to expressions

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VSCode, you can add this to your `launch.json`

```json
{
  "name": "Haxe Interpreter",
  "type": "haxe-eval",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "launch task here",
},
```

then add a breakpoint, and start the debugging session.

Comment: I tried that before but the problem is that the macro code is so large that the only way I can see that working is by debugging "expanded" macro.